# Regex: Delete all lines not containing ":" at the 4th letter of each line

Tags: notepad++

For example:

```
abc1234:sdfasdfd
abc:sdfsaffsfs
```

It would delete the line with `abc1234` but keep `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

The RE for matching lines according to your criteria, i.e. without a colon as the fourth character, is `^...[^:]`

- `^` Start of line
- `...` Three wildcard characters
- `[^:]` Not (`^`) a colon (`:`)

In Notepad++, use <kbd>Ctrl F</kbd> to open the Find dialog, go to the [Mark] tab, and choose to Bookmark lines. Run the search to bookmark the lines that don't match.

Now go to Search > Bookmarks > Remove bookmarked lines, and your selected lines will be removed.

Comment: Alternatively if OP has access to something like vim or sed (using WSL for example) then its trivial to do this in-file with a single command, but this is (most likely) the next best way using notepad++ only anyhow

Comment: The OP has tagged with [tag:notepad++] so that's what I assumed they wanted to use. Me, I'd have used `grep`, `sed`, or `vi` depending on the context

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go in a single step:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^...[^:].*\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  ...       # 3 any character but newline
  [^:]      # 1 character that is not colon
  .*        # 0 or more any character
  \R?       # optional any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]